# Laravel : Function Always Insert One Number To DB In LOOP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, while-loop

I want create some random codes based on miliseconds.
when i use "var_dump" it shows my function is working correctly and too many $result numbers are created. but when i use ORM INSERT Statement to save them into my database , it always SAVE : 2147483648 in database and it seems it's not depended on my $result !!!!!
here is my code :

```
    public function Timer($Number)
    {
$i=0;
        while ($i<$Number)
        {
            $microtime = microtime(true);
            $milliseconds = sprintf("%02d", ($microtime - floor($microtime)) * 96 * 62 * 23 * 43);
            $result=date('His'. $milliseconds, $microtime)."";
            $result=substr($result,1,11);
            DB::table('form')->insert([
                'Number' => $result,
                'IsValid' => false
            ]);
$i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to insert here? The bizarre use of `sprintf` and `substr` and `date` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I'm getting time in Millisecond and multiple it to some random numbers and get first 11 numbers to create a random and unpredictable code. but my problem is not about the use of this algorithm... my question is about the problem that i said !

Comment: Nothing in this is random or unpredictable. If you want random values, use something like [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2147483647` is [maximum number for signed `INT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html). So, try to use unsigned `BIGINT` or `VARCHAR` to store the value.

Or you could use another way to build random codes, like [`str_random()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-random) or something similar.

Comment: `BIGINT` is preferable to `VARCHAR` for numerical data.

Comment: @tadman, if OP just wants to get some random code, so it doesn't matter what he uses. If he wants to keep numbers then sure, `BIGINT` will be best choice. But what if he wants to generate something like `292232322433724036854775807`. Even `BIGINT` will not be able to store this.

Comment: I like your `str_random()` idea since that's less likely to have collisions.